# Am I missing a print command somewhere?

Tags: python, file, for-loop

My assignment is to make a program that read the numbers from a file, then display the average of those numbers.  So:

```
def main ():
    #open the file numbers.txt, this file is located in the IDLE directory
    #on my flash drive.
    numbers_file = open(r'{file path}\numbers.txt', 'r')
    number_total = 0
    #read each line of the file, numbers.txt
    line = numbers_file.readline()
    #declare a line counter, this will be needed to determine the average of
    #all the numbers in the file
    line_number = 1
    #check that the line is valid, as long as an emptry string is not
    #returned, continue
    while line != '':
        #convert the line to a float
        number_entry = float(line)
        #count what line that was
        line_number += 1
        #add the current number in the line to the total of the lines so far
        number_total += number_entry
    #when the last line is read,
    file_average = number_total/line+number
    numbers_file.close()
    print(file_average)

#call the main function
main ()
```

I run it ... and I wait ... and wait and wait and wait ...

`numbers.txt` only has 10 numbers in it; this should finish in a split second.  What did I miss?

Comment: Your while loop isn't breaking anywhere.

Comment: Currently, you aren't iterating through the file. You read the first line, then enter an infinite loop which never reads the next line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading the first line only with

```
line = numbers_file.readline()
```

and then in your `while` loop you are expecting value of `line` to change.  This would require you to call `readline` method also in the loop. But you have a more pythonic option, taking advantage of the fact that `file` object implements `iterator` interface.

Remove `line = numbers_file.readline()` and change `while line != '':` loop into:

```
for line in numbers_file:
```

Comment: *face palm* Doh! Yeah that did it. Always the simple stuff.

Though now I have a new... complication. The program runs, adds the numbers and then displays an average, but it's not the right average. At present numbers.txt contains the number 1-10 (1,2,3...) Add those us and it comes to 55, divide that by 10 and it should come out to 5.5. But the program displays 5.0. I declared file_average to be a float, but to no effect. What the heck?

Comment: file_average is a float, I changed it the first I ran the program and got that result.

Comment: Ah, right `line_number = 1` is the problem. Change it to `line_number = 0`.

Comment: nevermind. My mistake. I forgot I changed some things to trouble shoot. thanks.

Comment: I mean the assignment before the loop, not incrementation inside it.

Comment: So leave `line_number += 1` as it is and change `line_number = 1` into `line_number = 0`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157323/discussion-between-michael-cividanes-and-elmovankielmo).

Answer (score 2):

**line** does not change within the loop, and there's no **break**; once you enter the loop, you're stuck.  I expect that what you need is to move (or replicate) the **readline** within the loop.

```
while line != '':
    number_entry = float(line)
    line_number += 1
    number_total += number_entry

    #read the next line
    line = numbers_file.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 file_average = number_total/line+number
```

After the while loop you are using `line` toget average. Is that really required. Or are you finding each line average then place in while loop.

Comment: that's a type. it's not 'number_total/line+number' it's supposed to be 'number_total/line_total'.